# What is the correct mime type for less?

Tags: less, mime-types, content-type

Is there a official mime type for less files? I have not found anything in http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text. If there is no official mime type, what is the best practice?

Should I use something like text/x-less or text/less?

Comment: I don't know why you need that mime type at all. Your less should be compiled to css

Comment: @danielspaniol I want to use the less sources. (I know that that less is usually compiled to css.)

Comment: Why do you want a mime type? Answering what is your purpose may help answer what type you should use.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO Why office documents has mime types?

Comment: @TN. good question,  :-)  I guess "historical reasons" covers it - the history of "how to identify random files" is quite a long fight between 1) magic numbers (lots of formats have these but not all) 2) external labels (like mime) and 3) File extensions. All three are used to some extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source code files don't in general have MIME types associated with them. For example there is no MIME type for FORTRAN, Basic (any dialect), Perl, Bash, C, C++ and so on. Oddly, SQL has one though.

CSS and JavaScript need MIME types because they are interpreted by the browser so need to be identified by the browser. JSON ditto. Jose has a MIME type because it must be identified as such by the server.

In your case, unless you have some special requirement to identify LESS files as such to an automatic tool, I suggest `text/plain`.

You will in any case be identifying the file by the `filename-parm` in your https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt compliant `Content-Disposition` header, so there should be no issue with the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

The MIME types were introduced to give the browsers and email clients a hint about how the content of the files or emails should be rendered or what helper programs to use to open them when the browser/email client cannot render them. Also, there are MIME types that tell the browser to save the file (to not attempt to open it).

Since the LESS files are not meant to be interpreted by the browser in any way and, even more, they are not even meant to be downloaded, assigning a special MIME type for them is a waste of time.

In such situations, the recommended way is to use a broader MIME type that covers the format.

For LESS files, the only MIME type that matches is: `plain/text`.